# How can I have a figure or a table in tikzset?

Tags: tables, tikz-styles, nicematrix, tikzset

Here is the code for Convolutional neural network.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\mbox{}\vfill\arraybackslash}m{50pt}<{\vfill}}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[rectangle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,2}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left: \y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    \node[output neuron, right of=H-2] (O) {};

    \foreach \source in {1,...,2}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\newline \\

\begin{tabular}{ | c >{\columncolor{red}} l  l |}
    \hline
     &  &  \\
    \rowcolor{red}
     &  &  \\
     &  &  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I want to use a figure or a table instead of rectangle in `\tikzstyle{neuron}=[rectangle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]`. My table is 2x2 and probably it is not possible split a node horizontally and vertically.

Any solution for this problem?
Here is the code for my table that I want to have it instead of rectangle.

```
\begin{tabular}{ | c >{\columncolor{red}} l  l |}
    \hline
    &   &  \\
    \rowcolor{red}
    &   &  \\
    &   & \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: The output should look like this pic]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you make your code example complete, i.e., add the documentclass, `\usepackage` statements, `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` etc., so that the output is reproducible without extra effort from potential answerers? Also it is not entirely clear to me what you want to output to look, maybe you can make a mock-up screenshot in a paint tool?

Comment: Do you want every neuron to be drawn with a table? What do you mean to write inside those tables? It's not clear enough. And, btw, the use of `tikzstyle` is deprecated nowadays. You may use only `tikzset`.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you. I have added some \usepackage. The code works correctly.

Comment: @SebGlav Yes, I want every neuron to be drawn with a table like the picture I attached

Comment: Note that figure and table are floats which may or may not include images and tabulars.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am new to Latex and trying to solve this problem for 2 days:S

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reproduce the posted figure illustrating a convolutional neural network without `\tikzset`.

In fact, `\tikzset` won't help here much since each of the seven arrays is different.

I used `nicematrix` as a tabular environment because it works by creating `Tikz\PGF` nodes, so it fits perfectly with `tikzpicture`, producing a very compact code.

It is the only additional package required. (I commented on the other unused packages for this example)

[image: a]

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
%\stackMath

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

%\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}
%\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
%\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\mbox{}\vfill\arraybackslash}m{50pt}<{\vfill}}
%\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\inputImg}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{3}{>{\bfseries}c}}[cell-space-top-limit = 6pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 6pt,
    hvlines, code-before=\chessboardcolors{red!15}{gray!15}]    
1   &   -1  &   1   \\  
-1  &   1   &   -1  \\  
1   &   -1  &   1 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw[green!80!blue, ultra thick] (row-2-|col-1) -- (row-2-|col-3)-- (row-4-|col-3)-- (row-4-|col-1)-- cycle; 
\end{NiceTabular}   
}

\newcommand{\filteri}{%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{>{\color{green!80!blue}\bfseries\footnotesize}wc{2pt}}}[cell-space-top-limit = 1pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 1pt,  hvlines, code-before=\chessboardcolors{blue!15}{gray!15}]       
    + & -  \\   
    - & +       
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\filterii}{%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{>{\color{green!80!blue}\bfseries\footnotesize}wc{2pt}}}[cell-space-top-limit = 1pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 1pt,  hvlines, code-before=\chessboardcolors{gray!15}{blue!15}]       
    - & + \\    
    + & -       
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\firstlayeri}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{>{\bfseries}c}}[cell-space-top-limit = 7pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 7pt,
    hvlines, code-before=\cellcolor{gray!25}{1-1,1-2,2-1}]      
    4                   & -4  \\    
\color{green!80!blue}-4 &       
\end{NiceTabular}   
}

\newcommand{\firstlayerii}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{9pt} p{9pt}}[cell-space-top-limit = 4pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 4pt,
    hvlines]        
     &   \\ 
     &      
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\resulti}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{16pt} p{16pt}}[cell-space-top-limit = 8pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 8pt,
    hvlines,  code-before=\chessboardcolors{white}{gray!25}]        
    &   \\  
    &   
\CodeAfter
\tikz{%         
    \draw[color=red, ultra thick] (row-1-|col-1) -- (row-2-|col-2);  
}           
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\resultii}{%
    \begin{NiceTabular}{p{16pt} p{16pt}}[cell-space-top-limit = 8pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 8pt,
        hvlines]        
        &   \\  
        &           
    \end{NiceTabular}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,thick , draw=black!80]
    \sffamily
    
    \node(x0) at (0,0){\inputImg};
    \node(x1) at (2,2){\filteri}; 
    \node (x2) at (2,-2){\filterii};
    \node (x3) at (4,2){\firstlayeri};
    \node (x4) at (4,-2){\firstlayerii};
    \node (x5) at (8,2){\resulti};
    \node (x6) at (8,-2){\resultii};
    
    \draw[->] (x0) -- (x3);
    \draw[->] (x0) -- (x4);
    \draw[->] (x3) -- (x5);
    \draw[->] (x4) -- (x6);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Going back to your code, and using the same technique, I replaced the output rectangle with an array (with its own internal nodes inside!). Only a single line was changed inside of the `tikzpicture` code.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{stackengine,amsmath}
\stackMath
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage[boxsize=1.25em, centerboxes]{ytableau}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\mbox{}\vfill\arraybackslash}m{50pt}<{\vfill}}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\usepackage{nicematrix} % added

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\ouputImg}{% added <<<<
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{3}{>{\sffamily}c}}[cell-space-top-limit = 6pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 6pt,
    hvlines,code-before=\rectanglecolor{red!20}{1-1}{3-3}]  
    32  &   11  &   7   \\  
    9   &   4   &   22  \\  
    15  &   2   &   10 
\end{NiceTabular}   
}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[rectangle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,2}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left: \y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    \node[ right of=H-2] (O) {\ouputImg};  % <<<<<<<< changed


    \foreach \source in {1,...,2}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

See [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles/52385)

about using of `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle`

Comment: Thank you Simon. I’ve solved it in a different way but your solution is very simple to understand. Thanks